# Picking timeseries from SQL database in source priority order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time-series

I need to pull a timeseries from a table that looks about like this

TimeStamp (timestamp), Datapoint (float), Data_source (integer)

So the following query would give me all the data recorded by source 1.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE data_source = 1
```

Now, how do I pick so that data_source = 1, is prioritized over the other sources? ie. I don't want doubles, I always want a datapoint which preferably is from source 1, but if not available pick something else.

I did this with a subquery that counted the amount of source=1 for every row. But that is incredibly slow. There must be an efficient way to do this? Source 1 is only available for about 3% of the points. There may be multiple other sources for one point, but in general any other source will do.

I'm on ms sql 2008. So T-SQL would be preffered, but i think this problem is quite general?

Comment: What constitutes a double? Timestamp? Datapoint? Something not listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to combine your data into a single series, prefering source 1.

How about this:

```
select timestamp,
       datapoint
from (select t.*,
             min(data_source) over (partition by timestamp) as minDataSource
      from t
     ) t
where data_source = minDataSource
```

This assumes that "1" is the smallest data source.  It calculates the min data source for each time stamp, and then uses the data from that data source.

Comment: Cool, thanks, that's a clearly better subquery than what I used. I think this can not be done without a subquery though. I changed it just a bit, so that all tables are not called t (ie. one wants to have another letter inside the subquery)